# Pyinstaller won't open the external .txt files of the python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, user-input, pyinstaller

EDIT

This is my code:

```
import pyperclip
text_file = open("dewey.txt", "rt")                     #Open the list containing the values
text = text_file.read().split('\n')
text_file.close()


num = []
with open ('dewey num.txt', 'rt') as in_file:           #Open the list containing the keys
    for line in in_file:
        num.append(line[:3])
intenum = []
for i in num:
    intenum.append(int(i))                              #Make the keys as integers


dict1= dict(zip(intenum,text))                          #Merge the 2 lists in a dictionary
print ('This software will give you the subjects for each stack.')                                  #Instructions for the user
print ('I need to know the range first, please only use the first three numbers of the classmark.') #Instructions for the user

x=input('Please key in the starting number for this stack: ')                                       #Input for start
y=input('Please key in the last number for this stack: ')                                           #Input for stop

start = int(x)
stop = int(y)

values = [dict1[k] for k in range(start, stop + 1) if k in dict1]                                   #Call the values in range
print('The subject(s) for this section: ')
for i in values:                                                                                    #Print the values in range
    print (i)
output = '\n'.join (values)
pyperclip.copy(output)
```

It's working as it should within python, so I compiled it to .exe using Pyinstaller.

I managed to have an exe file now but I'm struggling with the import of pyperclip.

the exe works except for that last command. I tried -p dir and also --hidden-import pyperclip.

I ran it with -d and the debug I get is:

```
PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
LOADER: executable is C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\dist\deweycheck\deweycheck.exe
LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\dist\deweycheck
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\dist\deweycheck\deweycheck.exe
LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\dist\deweycheck)
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\dist\deweycheck\python35.dll
LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\dist\deweycheck\base_library.zip;C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\dist\deweycheck
LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\dist\deweycheck
LOADER: Setting runtime options
LOADER: Initializing python
LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\dist\deweycheck\base_library.zip;C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\dist\deweycheck
LOADER: Setting sys.argv
LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
LOADER: extracted struct
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
LOADER: callfunction returned...
LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
LOADER: PYZ archive: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
LOADER: Running dewey.py
```

I'm not sure how to proceed right now :\ any input?

Comment: Are you using `one-file` or `one-dir`?

Comment: To troubleshoot you also add `print os.getcwd()` at the beginning of the code and see which is the current folder for the frozen code.

Comment: thanks for your response, @Repiklis, I starte with one file but then it worked with the directory just by copying the necessary files in the same folder. So I managed to have the exe but the last command 'pyperclip.copy(output)' is not working in the exe. probably the import didn't work correctly within the exe. I checking this now.

Comment: I think you are missing the `pyperclip` dependencies. Check [this](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to import all the dependencies by using the command 'pyi-makespec' which then required an additional step to make the actual exe file. The documentation for pyinstaller is really extensive and accurate. Thanks @Repiklis for your inputs

Comment: Can you share the link or elaborate how you solved this issue?